# React:Can not props data from father to child

Tags: reactjs

This is simplified of my problem.Child component can not get props from Father.

`Father.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Child from './Child'

class Father extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
}

    render() {
        var data = "any data"
        return (
                <div>
                    <Child data={data}/>
                </div>
    );
}}

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Father/>
  }
})
```

`Child.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props)            // miss the value ,it return {}
    }

    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.data}</div>
    }
}


export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Child/>             //  mark A
  }
})
```

At the `Child.construor`,`console.log(props)` return `{}`.
And in the final webpage, shows nothing.

How to let Child component get props from Father?

If I change the line at `mark A` to

```
return <Child data= "any..data"/>
```

It will show right.
Is there any strict rule?

Comment: do not use `createClass`, use `export default Father`; and `export Default Child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are complicating the things. When you create a component using class method, you dont need to use `React.createClass`. All you need is

```
export default class Father extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

    render() {
        var data = "any data"
        return (
                <div>
                    <Child data={data}/>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props)            // you will get the value here
    }

    render(){
        return <div>{this.props.data}</div>
    }
}
```

to understand what the problem is, you need to know that  you had an intermediate class which isn't passing the data from parent to the child. In the below code

```
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    console.log(this.props); // here you will see the props pass down from the parent
    return <Child/>   // here you are creating the instance of child component  but you are not passing any prop to it
  }
})
```

Note that if you write

```
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Child  {...this.props}/>   
  }
})
```

it will work, but you don't need it since you are already creating components using class method